Copy multiple files in Makefile using freebsd make
I'm trying to copy multiple files from one directory to another via a Makefile.
However this does not work...
SHELL=/bin/bash
copy:
     @cp /dir1/dir2/{file1,file2} /dir3/

Output:
cp: /dir1/dir2/{file1,file2}: No such file or directory
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make: stopped in /dir1/dir2

Specifying a single file at a time works though
SHELL=/bin/bash
copy:
     @cp /dir1/dir2/file1 /dir3/
     @cp /dir1/dir2/file2 /dir3/

This issue is specific to freebsd make (/usr/bin/make) and the same Makefile works with gmake on freebsd (/usr/local/bin/gmake).
So can I assume that freebsd make doesn't understand the braces syntax in paths? And any tweaks with which I can correct my Makefile according to freebsd make syntax?

It's the shell that expands these braces, not make.  Make just passes the value to the shell.  All I can assume is that setting the SHELL variable is not enough / not sufficient to tell freebsd make which shell to use, so it's still using the default /bin/sh which doesn't support brace expansion.

It's the shell that expands these braces, not make.  Make just passes the recipe commands to the shell.  In FreeBSD make, the SHELL variable doesn't change the shell.  In this way I suppose FreeBSD make does not conform to POSIX.
In FreeBSD make, you have to use the .SHELL special target instead.  See: https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?make(1)
Since .SHELL isn't important to GNU Make, you can just add it to your makefile and GNU Make will ignore it.

Hey, thanks a lot! @MadScientist, that worked. However, I had to specify name as sh/ksh/csh with path of bash like .SHELL: name=sh path=/bin/bash.
Specifying name as bash, or setting .SHELL=/bin/bash didn't work.

Right.  I didn't read carefully enough that the .SHELL variable is read-only in FreeBSD make.  However GNU Make will ignore that extra target, as well, as long as you don't try to run it :)

PS please don't use csh with makefiles.  Or at all.  Ever.  shudder

yup, Thanks @MadScientist
Sure, staying away from csh ;)
